# Redirect in WordPress plugin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, wp-redirect

I am learning WordPress plugin development. I am trying to redirect user to plugins home page after submitting a Form. My code is like below

```
wp_redirect(plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)); 
exit;
```

But I am getting `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/):

> wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to `exit;`:

```
wp_redirect( plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) );
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks @Cadu De Castro Alves for your answer. But your solution is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post the code of the form?